# Как записать переменную в value у input в зависимости от условия?

Tags: vue.js

проект на vue.
есть input где

```
:value="'${type}'"
```

значение type получаем с базы. оно может быть 1 и 2. где 1 - самовывоз, 2 - доставка. вместо 1 и 2 надо выводить слова. понимаю, что должно быть что-то типа:

```
if (type ===1){
 value = 'самовывоз'
} else {
 value = 'доставка'}
```

где и как это можно указать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Так а зачем вам input? 
Если надо вывести один вариант из 2, то используйте {{ type === 1 ? "Самовывоз" :  "Доставка"}}
Если прям очень надо запихнуть в input, используйте return type === 1 ? "Самовывоз" :  "Доставка" в computed, а в input вставьте захешированный результат :value="result"
Для использования конструкции ${type} используйте косые кавычки ``